# SSIS C# Script : convert xml to xls format

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

i need SSIS c# script which convert `.xml` data into `.xls`
format

please help.

Comment: Might be helpful if you could give an example of the data you're trying to convert and how you expect it to look, as well as how far you've managed to get so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These forums might be good for what you are trying to archive

http://venkat-dotnetsnippets.blogspot.com/2010/07/import-xml-file-to-sql-server-using.html

http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-dts/10784/Importing-XML-files-to-SQL%20-Database-using-SSIS

Answer (score 1):

Could do with some more details on the data that you are actually trying to import.

The XML source reader is part of the [standard packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140277.aspx).
And so is the [excel destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137643.aspx)

Meaning that in theory there isn't anything getting in your way. It's all about how complex your data can be. Especially because SSIS won't be doing any validation of its structure for you.

Also, bear in mind that exporting to excel can be a bit of a finicky process. Unless there is an specific requirement for this. I would recommend you to export to plain csv instead, which can also be opened in Excel and formatted prettily at a later stage.